# Highcharts inverted line where dates go upwards, not downwards (reversed series)?

Tags: highcharts

I have implemented similar chart than this demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-inverted

How can I reverse the series the date axis so that dates ascend towards top?

EDIT: Actually I got the demo's fiddle working but not this real one. I will try to mirror it to fiddle and post a link here...

UPDATE: Got it working. Here is a demo of dates going upwards and the dataset is timestamped data, dateformat is weekday and no categories used!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. Here is a demo of dates going upwards and the dataset is timestamped data, dateformat is weekday and no categories used: http://jsfiddle.net/ryfssm1u/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        inverted: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -150,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        reversed: false,
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{value:%a}'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {

    },
    series: [{
        type: 'spline',
        color: '#bb2a9d',
        lineWidth: 2,
        pointInterval:  24 * 3600 * 1000,
        data: [
           [ 1433297870000,     85 ],
           [ 1433211470000,     22 ],
           [ 1433125070000,     32 ],
           [ 1433038670000,     54 ],
           [ 1432952270000,     36 ],
           [ 1432865870000,     76 ],
           [ 1432779470000,     34 ],
           [ 1432693070000,     85 ]
       ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: the key being the **reversed: false** setting